# Asp.Net Storefront Product Listing Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspdotnetstorefront

I am using Asp.Net Storefront 7.0 version. I want to create the custom page which allows users to browse all the products in the single page. I searched for the page in the website solution which is responsible to perform this product browsing task but i didn't find any specific page ( as this system was developed by other developer ).

So can i have the example which queries the database for the products with discount and other information. and from that custom page the user can place the order ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say looking at this in two ways. You can either look at adding some bespoke SQL to retrieve the products that you want displayed and then either modifying the columns and rows shown per page or just showing all with a wildcard search term.

Example would be

SQL to display products

```
 <query name="Products" rowElementName="Product">
    <sql>
        <![CDATA[
            exec dbo.Show_GetProducts 
                @categoryID = @CatID,
                @sectionID = @SecID,
                @manufacturerID = @ManID,
                @distributorID = @DistID,
                @genreID = @GenreID,
                @vectorID = @VectorID,
                @localeName = @locale,
                @CustomerLevelID = @CustLevelID,
                @affiliateID = @AffID,
                @ProductTypeID = @ProdTypeID, 
                @ViewType = 1,
                @pagenum = @pgnum,
                @pagesize = @pgsize,
                @StatsFirst = 0,
                @publishedonly = 1,
                @ExcludePacks = 1,
                @ExcludeKits = 1,
                @ExcludeSysProds = 0,
                @InventoryFilter = @InvFilter,
                @sortEntityName = @entityname,
                          @storeID = @StoreID,
                @filterProduct = @FilterProduct,
                 @sortEntity = @sortentity,
                 @filterLetter = @filterletter


        ]]>
    </sql>
    <queryparam paramname="@CatID"              paramtype="runtime"     requestparamname="CatID"                                                          sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@SecID"              paramtype="runtime"     requestparamname="SecID"                                                          sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@ManID"              paramtype="runtime"     requestparamname="ManID"                                                          sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@DistID"             paramtype="runtime"     requestparamname="DistID"                                                         sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@GenreID"          paramtype="runtime"       requestparamname="GenreID"                                                    sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@VectorID"           paramtype="runtime"     requestparamname="VectorID"                                                   sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@locale"             paramtype="runtime"     requestparamname="LocaleSetting"                                          sqlDataType="varchar" defvalue="en-US"  validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@CustLevelID"      paramtype="runtime"       requestparamname="CustomerLevelID"                                    sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@AffID"              paramtype="runtime"     requestparamname="AffiliateID"                                            sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@ProdTypeID"       paramtype="runtime"       requestparamname="ProductTypeFilterID"                                sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="1"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@pgnum"              paramtype="request"     requestparamname="pagenum"                                                      sqlDataType="int"         defvalue="1"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@pgsize"             paramtype="request"     requestparamname="pagesize"                                                     sqlDataType="int"         defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@InvFilter"        paramtype="appconfig" requestparamname="HideProductsWithLessThanThisInventoryLevel" sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@entityname"       paramtype="runtime"       requestparamname="EntityName"                                                   sqlDataType="varchar"   defvalue=""       validationpattern="" />
        <queryparam paramname="@StoreID"            paramtype="runtime"     requestparamname="StoreID"                                                      sqlDataType="int"         defvalue="1"      validationpattern="" />
    <queryparam paramname="@FilterProduct"  paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="FilterProduct"                                                sqlDataType="bit"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
<queryparam paramname="@sortentity"  paramtype="request"   requestparamname="sortEntity"  sqlDataType="int" defvalue="0"       validationpattern="" />
<queryparam paramname="@filterletter"  paramtype="request"   requestparamname="filterletter"  sqlDataType="varchar" defvalue=""       validationpattern="" />
</query>
```

Then somewhere in the page have something like this to display the products

http://www.example.com/c-123-mypage.aspx?sortEntity=&pagenum=1&pagesize=9999&filterletter=%